# GemFire 9 replacement of GemfireUtilLauncher

Tags: java, apache, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Is there a replacement for the `GemfireUtilLauncher` previously found at:
`com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.GemFireUtilLauncher`?

Following documentation everything should be updated to:
`org.apache.geode.X.X` but no such `GemfireUtilLauncher` exists in these new versions and there does not seem to be a jar file that incorporates it (e.g. `geode-core` instead of `gemfire-core`).

The closest example of the class I can find is at the following link but there does not seem to be any documentation for the most recent change...

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=incubator-geode-master/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/GemFireUtilLauncher.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GemfireUtilLauncher](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.0.0-incubating.M1/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/GemFireUtilLauncher.java) class was removed after Apache Geode 1.0.0-incubating.M1.

> NOTE: If you are not aware of this, [Apache Geode](http://geode.apache.org/) is the *open source core* of [Pivotal GemFire](https://pivotal.io/pivotal-gemfire).

A few things to keep in mind here...

1. First, and most importantly, you should never use "**internal**" classes that are not part of the [Apache Geode](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/index.html) or [Pivotal GemFire](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/) **public API**.  The classes are "**internal**" for reason and therefore are subject to change without notice or consideration to end-users applications.
2. Second, and as apparent from the [Javadoc](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.0.0-incubating.M1/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/GemFireUtilLauncher.java#L31-L47) in the source code, this class was used to support the now "*deprecated*" and old GemFire shell scripts for starting processes, namely: `agent`, `gemfire` and `cacheserver`, [as mentioned here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.0.0-incubating.M1/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/GemFireUtilLauncher.java#L38-L40).  These shell scripts are no longer used and have been replaced by *Gfsh* ([doc](http://gemfire90.docs.pivotal.io/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/chapter_overview.html)) and the [LocatorLauncher](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.html) ([in Geode](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.html)) and [ServerLauncher](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/distributed/ServerLauncher.html) (in [Geode](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/distributed/ServerLauncher.html)) classes, which are part of the "public" API.

Regards,
-John